# OBSOLETE - StackTrace for iPad

Tags: app, obsolete, ipad

StackTrace for iPad is <del>[now available in the App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stacktrace/id515332899)</del> No longer in the iTunes store.

With StackTrace, we have taken a unique approach to consuming Stack Exchange content. Instead of focusing on finding answers to your current problems we're tailoring the experience for reading and discovery. There is significant, great content on Stack Exchange and lots can be learned from reading the experiences of others. A bit more of our approach can be found {slightly NSFW, dead link removed}.

Here's a few screenshots:

[image: StackTrace iPad app screenshot]

[image: StackTrace iPad app screenshot]

[image: StackTrace iPad app screenshot]

Comment: Looks great! Unfortunately I don't have an iPad to try it with - any chance we might see an Android version?

Comment: @GeorgeEdison We're starting with iPad but would love to expand to other mobile platforms. iPhone is our likely second platform (since we can leverage much of the Objective C codebase). However, Android is absolutely on our radar.

Comment: May I ask, why only SO?

Comment: @TimothyMueller-Harder Good question. If we would have focused on the entire Stack Exchange network, we would have ended up with a set of lowest common denominator features. Instead, we've baked in some features that really allow SO content to shine (full-screen code popups, syntax highlighting, etc). That said, we plan to grow to support the entire SE network when we feel confident we can give each of them the appropriate level of attention to detail.

Comment: So is the app readonly? Or are there any plans in giving the users the ability to respond to questions also?

Comment: @DennisRongo The Stack Exchange API is currently readonly, so we focused the app on reading and learning from the existing Stack Overflow content. Once there is an API that allows writes we will look in to adding those features.

Comment: Best looking Stack app for iPad by far!! Can't wait to try it.

Comment: @tim the app was just updated today to work with all Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @JeffAtwood Awesome, glad to hear it!

Comment: @bromanko can we log in to the site?

Comment: Please please please make an iPhone version! :D

Comment: This app doesn't appear to be available in non-US stores (at least, I can't get to it from the Australian store)